# can I store webjob timer schedule in a child object of appsetting.json?

Tags: azure-webjobs

if cron string is stored in the root of appsetting.json file, there is no problem to read them.
However, if I do this in appsetting.json:

```
"EETHistoryJobSettings": {
    "SomeSetting": {
      "Name": "A"
    },
    "Schedule": "*/15 * * * * *"
  }
```

and want the the timer to read from EETHistoryJobSettings json object, it doesn't work (basically can't find EETHistoryJobSetting.Schedule).

```
public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("%EETHistoryJobSetting.Schedule%", RunOnStartup = true)] TimerInfo timerInfo, ILogger logger,
```

Just wondering if there is a way to specify Cron time in a child object or has to be on the root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, the Azure Functions Timer Trigger [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=in-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp#attributes) is given that CRON Expression Variable should be wrapped in **%** symbols.

**Case 1**:

If your `appsettings.json` contains the code settings in the form of `local.settings.json`:

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "<Storage_Conn_String>",
    "CronExpression":"*/15 * * * * *"
    }
}
```

Then the Function Code will be:

```
public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("%CronExpression%", RunOnStartup = true)] TimerInfo timerInfo, ILogger logger
```

**Case 2**:

appsettings.json:

```
{
"ScheudleInfo":{
    "TimerTrigger1":{
        "CronExpression":"*/15 * * * * *"
        }
    }
}
```

Then the Function Code will be:

```
public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("%ScheudleInfo:TimerTrigger1:CronExpression%", RunOnStartup = true)] TimerInfo timerInfo, ILogger logger
```

Note: *When using the Azure Function Classes, the Storage account connection string, environment variables should be defined in the* `local.settings.json`.